# Get keys from object in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object

Got an StdObject like this

```json
    $object = {
        "id": 1026,
        "internal_name": "mochileandoporelmundo",
        "firstName": "Letizia",
        "lastName": "Cassetta",
        "totalClicks": 64971
    }
```

and I want to get the keys of the objects since the object ,might have different keys at some points, I want to return something like this

```
$array = ['id','firstName', 'lastName','totalClicks']
```

Tried using array_keys() to list the keys but didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You can type cast the `stdObject` to an array and use `array_keys`:

```php
var_dump(array_keys((array)$object));
```